# MimeKit await client.AuthenticateAsync(username, password) not working with string vars

Tags: mimekit

It's driving me crazzy!! I need to send smtp emails with an email from db (which i can later alter the email and the pwd as well). The thing is...it only connects if i set username and password inside quotes.
I'm using mimekit 3.2, .net6.0;

```
 using var client = new MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient {                   
                CheckCertificateRevocation = false,
                ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (s, c, h, e) => true,
            };
            
                ...
                try
                {

                    client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove("XOAUTH2");
                    await client.ConnectAsync(_smtpDetails.Server, _smtpDetails.Port, SecureSocketOptions.SslOnConnect, default);

                    await client.AuthenticateAsync("email@example.com", "mypwd"); This works but i need to authenticate using  await client.AuthenticateAsync(string.Username, string.Pwd)!!

                    await client.SendAsync(mimeMessage);
                }
                finally
                {
                    await client.DisconnectAsync(true);
                }
             }
```

...

I've tried to create credentials, a class, etc, but no success!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you find that you are having a problem where using hard-coded (quoted) strings works but using a string variable doesn't, the problem is ALWAYS that your string variables don't contain the value(s) that you think they contain.

Print out (or use the debugger) to verify that they contain EXACTLY what they are supposed to contain.

A very common problem is that the string variable contains whitespace at the beginning or end of the string value (or a newline sequence).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback....I did all of that! Debug shows the variables with the right values. i'll post a screenshot.